# Some Belgian Ale and Pilsner Lager

Tags: grammar

*I would prefer some Belgian Ale to a Pilsner Lager.*

Is this sentence grammatically correct in terms of using of determinators? I am not sure how to use the articles before the styles of beer.

Comment: Colloquially - i.e. right the the point of ordering beer - I'd drop both. "I'd prefer Belgian ale to Pilsner"

Answer (score 1):

"Some" is the word that may be unusual or unlikely, depending on the context, and it probably wouldn't be used in a  statement of general preference, and nor would "a" in that case.

**I prefer Belgian Ale to Pilsener.**

If offered a choice of beverage, it would be different. Let's say you were a guest at someone's home rather than ordering in a pub, and the host were pouring the beverage into glasses rather than bringing bottles:

**I'd like some Belgian Ale, please.**

But at a pub, you'd hear either "a" or no article at all:

**Belgian Ale.**

**Make mine a Pilsener.**